# Create Repeating Horizontal and Vertical dashed line using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have tried several examples but no luck on setting margin from left and top.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kyrx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally create this pattern by nesting two repeating linear gradients. See [Stripes in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/) for making stripes with gradients.

You make one gradient from left to right, then another one from top to bottom, and the end result is a grid as in your image.

```css
div {
  background-color: seagreen;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent 98px, white 100px, white 100px), repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 98px, white 100px, white 100px);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Setting the transparent worked for me as well. but unfortunately, I have few HTML controls above this and they need to be selectable.Like div & input box. They appear to be read-only after this. 

Basically, I am trying to create a view like "print preview"  where user will get idea when they will see page break after printing.

Comment: I am sure it is an issue with the `z-index`. In the example above, the z-index is set to 1, which means it overlaps the div. (Objects by default have a z-index of 0.) You could try setting relative position on your controls so that you can give them a z-index of 2 or higher (z-index only affects positioned elements). ***Or***, if your div is transparent anyway (unlike my snippet, which has a background color), you could probably just change the z-index to 0 or -1, and it'd work just as well without changing the z-index for anything else.

Comment: Sweet. In that case, if your problem is solved, please go ahead and accept the answer so others know. Cheers!